# BIRT NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin, noclassdeffounderror, birt

I have been searching the web for a while now and no solutions found have been working out for me. So, I turn to you.

I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I try to integrate the API of BIRT (an eclipse plugin for reports and documents). I copy paste their code, include ALL of the jar file in the lib folder (birt-runtime-4_2_2\ReportEngine\lib) and still I get the NoClassDefFoundError. What am I doing wrong? I cant find any useful information on their page. Furthermore, I have tried out a couple of other source codes, yet I still get the same problem. So i would argue that the imports of the jar-files might be faulty. But I cannot for the love of God find the fault is.

The code I have copy pasted (just to try out) is found here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Simple_Design_Engine_API_%28BIRT%29

The complete error message is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.getExtensionRegistry(ServicePlatform.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.createFactoryObject(ServicePlatform.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:297)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.createFactoryObject(Platform.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DesignEngine.<init>(DesignEngine.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DesignEngine.newSession(DesignEngine.java:142)
    at standard.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Just found something interesting. Will test it out and comment later

Comment: nope, turned out to be a dead end. All help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you running your application? The process that I use is to  right-click on my project and choose Run As Menu and then select 'Eclipse Application'. If you run as a regular java application, the eclipse library won't be added to the classpath.

Comment: That was definitly something to note. Thank you for the help.
I ended up using the plugin view and import the jar as a source project. Then, in the build path setup, I linked it to that project and now it seems as if it works. I get some null values here and there, but no exception of "NoClassDeffFoundError"-type.

Hope this helps somebody else ^^

Answer (score 2):

Except from Birt's jar files you will also have to copy some extra jars from Birt Runtime to Tomcat's WEB-INF folder.

- Download Birt Runtime from the following link: http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/
- In Birt Runtime you will find a folder called ReportEngine. In this folder there is a lib folder. Just copy it to your WEB-INF folder.

I had a similar problem and it worked for me. Take a look at my problem: [NoClassDefFoundError for Birt Class EngineException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875747/noclassdeffounderror-for-birt-class-engineexception)